# I need support for pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I am coding with python and using the module `pyautogui` (maybe this is important, I don't know I use 2 monitors):

```
import pyautogui

res = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("image.png")
print(res)
```

but my output isn't the posoyopm of box, it's `None`.

Why is it `None`?

Comment: Looks like you are using an old version that returns None instead of throwing an exception

https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html

NOTE: As of version 0.9.41, if the locate functions can’t find the provided image, they’ll raise ImageNotFoundException instead of returning None

Comment: Thanks for answer but i look for the version and i have the lasted one also 0.9.53 and i reinstalled it with python 3.9 and it still doesnt work i tryed with the absolute path but this isnt going too (C:\ExamplePath). I tried also make a screenshot with other programm other pictures and with the funktion pyautogui.screenshot() but it still get the output None

Comment: an output of None means that the image could not be found in the screenshot.

Comment: I get :) i have to make a screenshot with only the tool from pyautogui and cut it with the windows picture programm i tried all time with paint XD so i get this output. Thx so much